# How to display running counter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I have a table cell that contains a numerical value.

When changing the value, I want to create an effect where the counter moves up (or down) in 100 steps until reaching the new value.

I've tried something like the following (with the help of jQuery):

```
function update(element,newValue)
{
  var oldValue = parseFloat($(element).text());
  var diff = (newValue - oldValue) / 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    oldValue += diff;
    $(element).text(oldValue);
  }
}
```

However, Javascript doesn't seem to refresh the display until AFTER the script is done - thus there's no effect.

How do I make sure the intermediate values are displayed at each step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this is very jQuery orientated:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  animateCount : function (from, to, time) {
    var steps = 1,
        self = this,
        counter;

    if (from - to > 0) {
      steps = -1;
    };

    from -= steps;

    function step() {
      self.text(from += steps);

      if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
        clearInterval(counter);
      };
    };

    counter = setInterval(step, time || 100);
  }
});
```

Now just use:

```
$('#selector').animateCount(1,100);
```

Which will count to 1 to 100, with the number incrementing every 100 ms. The interval is an optional 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and the DOM share the same thread, so the display cannot refresh whilst script is currently executing.  It has to wait until the thread becomes idle.  You can only achieve what you're trying to do with a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) call, increasing each step with a timer instead of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the JQuery side of things, but here's a quick sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var t, max, i;

            function Increase(amount) {
                max = amount;
                i = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value);
                t = setInterval("SetIncrease()", 10);
            }

            function SetIncrease() {
                document.getElementById("count").value = ++i;
                if(i == max) {
                    clearTimeout(t);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="count" type="text" value="1"/>
        <input type="button" value="Up" onclick="Increase(100)"/>
    </body>
</html>
```